# SoftKeyboard pushes all the views

Tags: android, xml, user-interface, android-softkeyboard

I'm trying to make a chat layout. The problem is when I focus the EditText, softkeyboard appears and pushes everything up. I want it to push only bottom part with send instructions so that top (brown) header part and a recyclerview with messages are still visible. Something that facebook messenger app has. I tried putting "adjust pan, resize" and everything in manifest file, but it didn't work. Here is my default layout when nothing is in focus:[image]

And this is when I press the EditText and keyboard appears and shifts everything up:

[image] I can't see header anymore nor the message in recyclerView.

Basically I want all elements to stay visible at all times, so when Keyboard pushes up, header, messages and send are still visible to the user.

Here is my layout code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_profile"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_profile"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:src="@drawable/img_back" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_profile"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp" />
</LinearLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/ll_profile"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:isScrollContainer="false">

    <RelativeLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view_line"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:background="@color/gray_light_trans" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_send"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:weightSum="10">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_message"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="9"
                android:hint="Message" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_send"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Send" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv_chat"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@id/ll_send"
            android:layout_below="@id/view_line" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: what did you set for `android:windowSoftInputMode` in manifest?

Comment: as I wrote in the post, I tried both adjust pan and adjust resize in every combination there is, and still no effect

Comment: adjustPan moves your content but if you set adjustResize or not set anyting your content should not move.

Comment: Tried even removing everything, still no progress

Comment: Interesting. I tried your code its working fine for me. Can you show us your manifest too please?

Answer (score 0):

use android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" in your activity at manifest

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I was using a theme in my App activity that was fullscreen. When I removed fullscreen from main base theme, it's working.